# Get count summed across two columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working in Postgres and have the following `accounts` table:

```
account_number | integer
country1 | character varying(1000)
country2 | character varying(1000)
```

I want to get a count of accounts in each country, regardless of whether the country is `country1` or `country2`.

So if the content of the table was:

```
account_number,country1,country2
123,France,Germany
124,Switzerland,France
125,Germany
```

Then the desired output from the query would be:

```
France,2
Germany,2
Switzerland,1
```

I know how to do this for one country at a time (`select country1, count(*) from accounts group by country1`) but not for both countries simultaneously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
with cte as
(
select account_number, country1 as country
from table1
union all
select account_number, country2 
from table1
)
select country, count(*) as cnt
from cte
group by country
```

Comment: it just for alias. and when you use union/union all you need to alias the column at the first query :) @Richard

Answer (score 0):

I recommend unpivoting the data using a lateral join and then aggregating:

```
select country, count(*)
from t cross join lateral
     (values (country1), (country2)
     ) v(country)
where v.country is not null
group by country;
```

In addition to being a more concise way to write the query, it should be faster because the table is scanned only once.  This could be a very big win if the "table" is really a view or subquery.